# Screen location when the camera has been rotated

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using the Projection class of Google maps to obtain the screen location for points in a polygon with the aim of creating a GroundOverlay and drawing a custom line style as a Path.  The problem is when the camera is rotated the toScreenLocation method is returning incorrect results.

```
GroundOverlayOptions overlayOptions = new GroundOverlay();
Projection projection = map.getProjection();
LatLngBounds screenBounds = projection.getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
imageWidth = projection.toScreenLocation(screenBounds.northeast).x;
imageHeight = projection.toScreenLocation(screenBounds.southwest).y; 
_overlayOptions.positionFromBounds(screenBounds);

Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageWidth, imageHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
Paint paint = new Paint();
Path path = new Path();     

List<LatLng> points = polygon.getPoints();

Point startPos = projection.toScreenLocation(points.get(0));
path.moveTo(startPos.x, startPos.y);

for (int i = 1; i < points.size(); i++) {

    Point nextPos = projection.toScreenLocation(points.get(i));         
    path.lineTo(nextPos.x, nextPos.y);

}

path.lineTo(startX, startY);        
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

BitmapDescriptor bmpDesc = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp); 
overlayOptions.image(bmpDesc);
map.addGroundOverlay(overlayOptions);
```

The image below illustrates the problem.  When the map is orientated North the blue dashed line renders where it is supposed to but when the bearing is changed the result of toScreenLocation gives me warped coordinates.

[image]
[image]

I've attempted to apply a matrix rotate transformation on the bitmap

```
Matrix rotationMatrix = new Matrix();
rotationMatrix.postRotate(map.getCameraPosition().bearing, imageWidth / 2, imageHeight / 2);
```

and I have also tried using trigonometry to rotate the points.  Neither approach was successful.

So my question is how do you get the screen location of a LatLng that is independent of the camera orientation?

Answer (score 0):

I think the screen locations are correct. But you do not use them to paint directly into the screen, but into a bitmap, which is by default oriented north up. When you apply this bitmap as GroundOverlay it is rotated together with the map and thus the locations do no longer fit.

See also the Documentation:

> Bearing
>
> The amount that the image should be rotated in a clockwise direction. The center of the rotation will be the image's anchor. This is optional and the default bearing is 0, i.e., the image is aligned so that up is north.

I am not sure, but I think you have to use the current rotation of the map as negative bearing for your GroundOverlay to compensate the effect. And I am also not sure, how a tilt of the map can or must be compensated. I would just try. The anchor point should most probably be the center of the image.

But in any case, I think it's important to realize that the screen locations are not really wrong. They just have the real screen as reference system, which is different from the bitmaps system after it is rotated.